# How do you prove the operator of a function is also a function?

Tags: functions

Let: $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g: C \rightarrow D$ be functions. The *"product of"* $f$ and $g$ is the function defined as follows:

$[f \cdot g](x,y) = (f(x),g(y)),\forall(x,y) \in A\times C$

How do you prove that:

(a) Prove that $f \cdot g: A\times C \rightarrow B \times D$ is a function

(b) Prove that if $f$ and $g$ is injective, then $f \cdot g$ is injective.

(c) Prove that if $f$ and $g$ is surjective, then $f \cdot g$ is surjective.

Comment: you are forgetting some things I presume, (b) and (c) are wrong (take the identity mal $f:= id:\{*\}\to \{*\}$ and the map $g:\{1,2\}\to \{*\}$, then $f\times g$ is not injective, although f is, for the other counterxample consider $g:\{*\}\to \{1,2\}$ and do the same argument).
Also, what do you understand as a function.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry, I forgot to include g in (b) and (c)

Comment: then you can prove that it is wrong! or your definition is wrong, are you sure you did not forget anything, or maybe got the implications wrong? something like: if $f\times g$ injective and $C\neq \emptyset$ then f is injective? this would hold!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right, I forgot to add $g$ in (b) and (c). But how do you prove (a)? I think I'm missing something, and I can't seem to see the entire picture of the function.

Comment: what is your definition of a function, or is it only a map? and then it is kind of trivial. will post an answer for all soon, however, I can't proof a without knowing your definition of a function. Or do you just mean a map of sets

Comment: He told me that the clue here is to have ordered pairs of ordered pairs.

Comment: still I need your definition! if you said map i would be ok, but there are a shitload of different notions of functions out there, some see it only as differentiable or contiuous maps beetween euclidean vector spaces, other peopel even demand the domain to be $\mathbb{R}$. Also I am slowly doubting you are reading my comments

Comment: I just reviewed my notes, and he defines functions as a mapping.

Comment: pls call it a map.

Comment: ok, thank you for you patience. Then the functions above are maps then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

(a)to prove that it is a map, we need to show that the assignement is well defined. but since $x \in A\times C$ has a UNIQUE representative this is well defined, and since all $x\in  A\times C$ have the form $x=(a,c)$ this is a map.

(b) let $f\times g(x) = f\times g(y)$ then this means $(f(x_1),g(x_2))=(f(y_1),g(y_2))$. But this means that $f(x_1)=f(y_1)$ and $g(x_2)=g(y_2)$. Now since $f$ and $g$ are injective this implies $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2=y_2$ and in particular $(x_1,x_2)=(y_1,y_2)$. So $f\times g$ is injective.

(c) let $y \in B \times D$ then $y=(y_1,y_2)$. now since f and g are surjective there exists $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f(x_1)= y_1$ and $g(x_2)=y_2$. In particular $$f \times g (x_1,x_2)=(f(x_1),g(x_2))=(y_1,y_2).$$
and so $f\times g $ is surjective.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you!